# Wakanda-Basic understanding

Tags: javascript, wakanda

I am looking for some basic help-i was using Wakanda about 18 months ago and then projects got in the way.

I am now trying again to write a project with it and struggling with some basic things.

I have page with a variable based data source on(as opposed to a Datastore Classes based object).

I want to pre-populate the value of this when the page is loading(this will take data either from session storage or from local storage).

I thought I understood what I was doing-create a variable with the same name and set the value of that and sync is the data source object

the object ID is `COLUserName` and the object value is `cOL_t_UserName`

in my javascript i have the following on load event code-the values are being set manually for the purposes of testing:-

```
documentEvent.onLoad = function documentEvent_onLoad (event)
    {

        var cOL_t_UserName = "test value"
sources.cOL_t_UserName.sync(); //advise the datasource of our change
```

but this does not set the on screen object on the loading of the form and debugging shows is is not syncing the value of the datasource object.

What am i doing wrong?

thank you to anyone coming back with answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the old way. A lot of change happens with Wakanda v1 release.

A quick step by step would be to:

- Create your model dataclasses in `/database/model.waModel`
- Populate you database with data using `backend` SSJS scripts
- Create your Web application (or mobile application) in `/web/`
- Get data from your backend to your frontend through wakanda-angular connector

I would suggest you to follow this [quick start tutorial](https://wakanda.github.io/angular-wakanda/#/doc/quickstart) on wakanda-angular connector. It helps you to do simple CRUD actions.

Good luck !

Comment: Yann. Thank you for coming back to me on that. I have made a couple of attempts now to work through the quickstart. Today was the first time i was able  really focus on it. I am however banging my head against the wall. Either I am doing something very wrong or i am missing something or there is something wrong with the instructions. There are significant errors on the walkthrough. Can you contract me off here( my email is known at 4D) and i can tell you what they are and maybe you can help me further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you remove 'var' in the onLoad event.

```
 documentEvent.onLoad = function documentEvent_onLoad (event) {

    objCol.userName = "test value";
    sources.objCol.userName.sync(); 
 };
```

With var, you create a 'locale' variable in the function. It 'surclass' your source and vanish.
I use an object datasource and a camelCase notation.
I hope this will help.